# Parse string from file and set to variable - Shell script

Tags: linux, shell, parsing, unix, scripting

I have a text file with a **single** line:

```
Our States M0->M1: 369 M0<-M1: 974 M1->M2: 165 M0<-M2: 164
```

I am trying to set a variable equal to what M0->M1 is. In this case it would be 369.

Currently what I have so far:

```
file="stats.txt"

while read line
do
    initial_m2=`grep "M0->M3 [0-9]+" $file`
    echo "$line"
done <"$file"
```

This prints:

```
(nothing - blank line)
Our States M0->M1: 369 M0<-M1: 974 M1->M2: 165 M0<-M2: 164
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just tyring to read the 4th column:

```
while read one two three initial_m2 blah; do
  echo $initial_m2
done < $file
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to figure it out after this response!